# Laravel Input Validation: How to check if all words in a string belong to a set of acceptable values?

Tags: regex, validation, laravel, input, laravel-4

I'm trying to use a Laravel (using Laravel 4.2) input validation rule that will make sure all the words in a string are included in a set of acceptable values.

For instance, the acceptable values might be: `'foo', 'bar', 'baz'`. So I want a rule that will accept `'foo, baz'`, or `'bar, foo, baz'`, but not 'something, else, entirely' or `'foo, qat, doo'`.

Will I have to create a custom validation rule for this? I also looked into using the predefined regex rule with something like `[[\s]*[foo|bar|baz]*[, ]*]*` but that didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Tried this https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-in?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but the in:rule only works for single values. So you pass in `foo` and the rule is `in:foo,bar,baz` and that will work. But if you pass `bar, foo`, and the rule is `in: foo,bar,baz`, that won't work.